# SUM of database function returns much higher value than actual SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database function that I am able to get the correct results from, but when I try to use SUM to total the results it returns a much higher value.

```
SELECT
  SUM([DATABASE].[dbo].[fn_GetCharges]([TABLE1_DATE],[TABLE1_CUST],[TABLE1_SITE],[TABLE1_SERV])) AS [GROSS_REVENUE]
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE
  [TABLE1_ROUT] = '1234'
  AND [TABLE1_DATE] = '2018-05-08'
```

This returns a SUM value of about 15,740.

If I remove the SUM and GROUP BY the function then it shows each of the returned values, which I manually totalled to about 750.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: You post the wrong code.  The one that has problem is your function.  But since you post the code that call the function instead of the function code itself, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know what is in your function, but you could probably output your raw data first and then sum it next.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
  [DATABASE].[dbo].[fn_GetCharges]([TABLE1_DATE],[TABLE1_CUST],[TABLE1_SITE],[TABLE1_SERV]) AS [GROSS_REVENUE]
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE1]
WHERE
  [TABLE1_ROUT] = '1234'
  AND [TABLE1_DATE] = '2018-05-08'
GROUP BY whatever_you_grouped_by_that_gave_correct_results
)

SELECT SUM(gross_revenue) AS gross_revenue
FROM cte
```

Comment: Yep, that worked! instead of using a subquery I created a temporary table like how you showed and joined it with my existing query. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Wondering if you used group by clause in the query  since I don't see one posted.
Group By (columns) Having (condition). What you specified in the 'where' goes in the 'Having' clause

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment. I understand that you don't have rep to comment, but please keep the answer section for answers only.